# Display Groups as headers and Group items in body in Bootstrap Accordion MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Can anyone help me with following:
I try to display Groups and Group Items in Bootstrap accordion, Main groups as accordion Headers and in Accordion body Group items for the main groups.

Now I have menu with sub-menus as main groups, and with passing parentID from Main Group, I can load only group items for one selected Group. What I want to achieve is to have load all groups and their group items at once in Accordion.

Can you please help me finding way to achieve this?

Thank You...

Here is example of my current menu:

[image: Current Menu with Main Groups]

Here is what I get:

[image: Current Result]

What I want to achieve:

[image: Trying to achieve]

Now I use this code in _Layout.cshtml for menu:

```
<li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Groups <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">          
                <li id="GroupSearch">@Html.ActionLink("Main Group 1", "GroupIndex", "Search", new {parentID = 1}, null)</li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li id="GroupSearch">@Html.ActionLink("Main Group 2", "GroupIndex", "Search", new {parentID = 2}, null)</li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li id="GroupSearch">@Html.ActionLink("Main Group 3", "GroupIndex", "Search", new {parentID = 3}, null)</li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li id="GroupSearch">@Html.ActionLink("Main Group 4", "GroupIndex", "Search", new {parentID = 4}, null)</li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li id="GroupSearch">@Html.ActionLink("Main Group 5", "GroupIndex", "Search", new {parentID = 5}, null)</li>

              </ul>
            </li>
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult GroupIndex(int? parentID = null)
        {
            ViewBag.Groups = articlesRepository.GetGroups(parentID);

            return View();
        }
```

And GroupIndex View:

```
@using Appp.Domain;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    var groups = (List<Appp.Domain.Entities.Groups>)ViewBag.Groups;

}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="list-group">
                @foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item" groupid="@group.ID">@group.Name</button>
                }
                <div class="list-group-item">
                    <form id="searchbygroupform">
                        <input id="groupid" name="groupid" type="hidden" />
                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchkeyword" id="searchkeyword" disabled>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="groupsearch" id="groupsearch" disabled>
                                    Serach
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This would be much easier to troubleshoot if you posted the *output* HTML instead of the input code. Well, I mean, you can post the output HTML *additionally* to that. Because this is primarily an HTML/Bootstrap issue.

Comment: You need to use a linq `.GroupBy()` clause to group you data by the main group